# binding more than one column of database in single column/header of datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hSWL.png)
this is the snippet of database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp2NU.png)
this is the snippet of xaml code

In second image 'id' is bound with header "Id". Now i want to bind 'first_name', 'middle_name' and 'last_name' in single header "Full Name".

Comment: Code so far? SO is not a code writing service

Comment: i do not have any idea what are you trying to say?

Comment: We do not provide assistance on SO unless you have made some reasonable progress yourself

Answer (score 0):

Add the new property in your model class name is FullName and where you assign the each db column in to your individual property of model class there you can assign the value for FullName through concatenate this 3 columns(First,Middle,Last Names). Now you can bind the FullName in your xaml file.

or

Write the converter

Comment: actually i am new to wpf so i would be grateful if you could assist me throughly step by step in coding